# importing data from excel sheet depending on the column title

Tags: database, excel

I need to do the following, Do let me know if its possible

I have a database in phpMyAdmin with say 'n' columns and an excel sheet with say 'm' columns. One of the columns is a reference number. What I need is, to import the data from the excel sheet to the phpmy database for the rowsof which the reference number matches in both excel and phpmy database. for each match, say 'l' number of columns (l is less than n,m) should be imported depending on the column title.

will be glad if someone could let me know if/how this is possible.

thank you

Comment: Is there anything at all that you have tried so far?